# Deployment on Openshift with Tomcat 7 show blank page

Tags: spring, git, maven, tomcat, openshift

When I insert the 'git push origin master' command for it to start Tomcat, it shows the error:

```
remote: [ERROR] Failed to perform 
org.apache.maven.plugins goal: maven-war-plugin: 2.1.1: war (default-war) on 
project sissopront: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (pre-
existing or WEB-INF / web.xml if executing mode in update)
```

and if I insert the plugin maven-war-plugin in pom.xml `<failOnMissingWebXml> false </ failOnMissingWebXml>`

it compiles regular successfully, but shows white page and nothing else.

Note: My war this renamed ROOT.war. I tried to put the tag `  ', but it shows error of not having found the web.xml

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the maven-war-plugin should be like

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
        <warName>ROOT</warName>
        <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven 
            needs to catch up! -->
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**OR** just create a basic web.xml in `APP_DIR/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

</web-app>
```